# Program type already present: com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeApiServiceUtil after migrating to AndroidX

Tags: androidx, android-youtube-api

After migrating my project to AndroidX (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) I get the following error:

Error: Program type already present: com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeApiServiceUtil

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me:

```
Migrate your project to AndroidX by selecting Refactor > 
"Migrate to AndroidX" from the menu bar.

Select Build > Clean project

Restore Android Studio
```

Now, I'm using YouTubePlayerSupportFragment and AndroidX in my project (Match4App) and I was able to publish it without any issues.

Comment: This task also allowed me to upgrade all other libraries that depend on AndroidX (i.e. com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.0.2, com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:18.0.1, com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0, com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0, etc.).